# how to encode password with special character for swiftmailer .env

Tags: php, symfony4, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmail to send emails with gmail.I have configured the MAILER_URL in my .env. But my password has got a special character in it. I've read that you must encode your password when there is a special character but I don't know how.

````
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=gmail://landabravo@gmail.com:landaB/24@localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There values need to be encoded using [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt]). Practically you can use PHP `urlencode()`.

So the value: `landaB/24` becomes: `landaB%2F24`

Comment: thanks! It works. I use https://www.urldecoder.org/ to encode special characters online